# Getting "Contract Compilation failed" error

Tags: remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying  to run my first contract and getting this error "Contract Compilation failed".

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract SimpleStorage {

uint storedData;

function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
}

function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
}
}
```

Am i doing any mistake? what should i do?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your contract as text so people can paste it into Remix? Your issue will probably go away if you select compiler 0.4.25 on the compile tab. There will also be a hint about why the new one doesn't like it.

Comment: Compilation of your contract works for me. Did you select a compiler version on the compile page?

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the below compiler version:

```
    0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1
```

That worked for me!